# Is there a way to modify $@ array in a POSIX shell script

Tags: shell-script, array, posix

I may know how to use `readlink` to get normal files from SymLinks. I had this very basic idea to replace any SymLink in `$@` passed to my function as follows:

```sh
for file in "$@"; do
    [ -L "$file" ] && file=$(readlink -f "$file")
done
```

Example would be a SymLink `/etc/os-release -> ../usr/lib/os-release`.

But if I do this:

```sh
set -- '/etc/os-release'; for file in "$@"; do [ -L "$file" ] && file=$(readlink -f "$file"); done; echo "$@"
```

I still get the original SymLink path, which is .. disappointing. I was hoping to be able to directly modify `$@`, if not possible, any there any workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your original code:

```sh
for file in "$@"; do
    [ -L "$file" ] && file=$(readlink -f -- "$file")
done
```

The issue is that setting `file` in the loop has no consequence to the contents of the list of positional parameters.

Instead, you may want to use

```sh
for file in "$@"; do
    [ -L "$file" ] && file=$(readlink -f -- "$file")
    set -- "$@" "$file"
    shift
done
```

Now we're shifting off the entries from the start of `"$@"`, one by one, and adding the possibly  modified entries to the back of the list.  Modifying `$@` in a `for` loop over `$@` is not an issue as `for` loops always iterates over a static list, i.e. the list that is iterated over is evaluated once at the start of the loop, only.

The loop above, like the ones below, resets the entire list of positional parameters in each iteration.  For a *huge* list of filenames, this may soon become quite slow.  If your shell has arrays, [Stephen Kitt's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/571643/116858) shows one way to speed it up.

The loop could also be written
in a slightly shorter form (calling `readlink` for each and every element),

```sh
for dummy do
    set -- "$@" "$(readlink -f -- "$1")"
    shift
done
```

This uses `readlink` as per your question, even though that's not a POSIX utility.

Note that if the output of `readlink` *ends with one or several newlines* (beside the one added to terminate the last line of output), these would be stripped off.  This is a consequence of the command substitution. If this is an issue, add a trailing character artificially in the command substitution, and then remove it, as `mosvy` suggests [in comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/571638/is-there-a-way-to-modify-array-in-a-posix-shell-script/571646?noredirect=1#comment1063701_571646):

```sh
for file do
    [ -L "$file" ] && file=$(readlink -f -- "$file"; echo x)
    set -- "$@" "${file%x}"
    shift
done
```

Comment: @LinuxSecurityFreak That would only be needed if you, like he suggests, call `readlink` with a _list_ of arguments.  The `set -f` is needed together with setting `IFS` to a newline, to split the result of such a call to `readlink` into multiple filenames. I did not do that here.  Note that doing so would disqualify filenames that contains embedded newlines (which is uncommon to have, but allowed).

Comment: @LinuxSecurityFreak That may be a good question. Consider doing a few searches on the site first to see if the topic has been covered before first.

Comment: Ok, will do later on. Right now heading offline. Thanks again.

Comment: You can work around the stripping of newlines via `r=$(readlink -f "$1"; echo x); set -- "$@" "${r%x}"`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Ouch. Thanks. I fixed that and the last loop too. Had too much other things to think about this morning...

Answer (score 0):

Note that neither `readlink` nor `realpath` are POSIX commands. The POSIX command line toolchest has no `realpath()`-like API. Here, instead of `readlink` (of which there exists different incompatible implementations), you could use `zsh` which also has a `realpath()`-like functionality built-in with its `:P` modifier. In your `sh` script:

```
eval "set -- $(zsh -c 'print -r ${(qq)argv:P}' zsh "$@")"
```

Though you might as well write your script in `zsh` in the first place, where it would just be:

```
argv=($argv:P)
```

Or if `python3` is more likely to be available than zsh:

```
eval "set -- $(
  LC_ALL=C python3 -c '
import sys, os, shlex
print(" ".join(map(shlex.quote, map(os.path.realpath, sys.argv[1:]))))' "$@")"
```